# How to get the relative position in set bit

Tags: c++, c, cuda, bit-manipulation

For simplicity to express, I assume the warp size is 8.
I have mask 10110110, returned by __ballot function, like above:

```
int cond = xxxx ? 1 : 0;
mask = __ballot(cond);
```

Now, I need the relative position in thread collection which thread satisfy the condition.

In the example above, the lane id = {1,2,4,5,7} satisfied the condition.
But, how to calculate the relative position with mask. For example, I have a function below:

```
mask = 10110110
function(mask, 1) -> 0
function(mask, 2) -> 1
function(mask, 4) -> 2
function(mask, 5) -> 3
function(mask, 7) -> 4
```

How to implement this function by bitwise operation ?

Comment: Note that you should not write function or variable names that start with an underscore, in general.  [C11 §7.1.3 Reserved identifiers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3) says that names starting with two underscores or an underscore and an upper-case letter are unconditionally reserved for the implementation, so `__ballot()` had better be provided by your system and not something you wrote.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I assume you are referring to `__ballot`.  That is CUDA-specific syntax, not created by OP, see [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#warp-vote-functions) which shows `__ballot_sync`; previous CUDA versions defined a function `__ballot` as part of the implementation.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Fine — my comment covers this case perfectly well.  It is something provided by the system, so the use is OK and my comment said so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the relative position, I would just mask the specific part of your ballot-mask and count these mask bits. Using CUDA's `__popc` to count bits, this is as easy as

```
int function(int mask, int pos)
{
    int m = (1 << pos) - 1;
    return __popc(mask & m);
}
```

That way, you calculate the number of set bits from the rightmost bit to the bit at the given pos, which is the relative possition of the set bits as you described it. Notice that this code won't actually count the bit at the given position, but only all set bits before that one.
In case you can't or don't want to use `__popc`, you can see implementations of calculating the [Hamming Weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) for bitoperation-only (and therefore portable) code.

Comment: Oh man, that works. Thank you so much. I tried several times, combine bitwise operations, struggled for a half hour. Your code is magic !!!

Comment: @gengliang allways glad to help :) Don't forget to mark this is answered if you like it ;)